# Bash Split Variable into 3 Variables based off Delimiters?

Tags: bash, variable, string

Trying to split a string var with the following pattern:

```
TestString="Artical Title Here (ClassYear) [Author]"
```

I was able to get the title into a Var using cut as such:

```
    ATH="$(cut -d'(' -f1 <<<$TestString)"
    echo $ATH
```

but I can't find a good way to get the (ClassYear) including the parentheses into another String variable, and same with the [Author] including the brackets, how do I get both those field and formats into 2 more variables?

Comment: your string is always in `xxx xxx xxx (xxx) [xxx]` format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the class year and author you could use grep.  Additionally you can use parameter expansion to get the title:

```
ath=${TestString/(*)*}
year=$(grep -o '(.*)' <<<"$TestString")
auth=$(grep -o '\[.*\]' <<<"$TestString")
```

This assumes the title will **never** have parentheses or brackets in it, the year will **always** be enclosed in parentheses, and the author will **always** be enclosed in brackets.

The `.` is a regex token that matches "Any single character" adding the `*` tells it to match zero to unlimited times.  So it should match literally anything enclosed in parentheses.  If you want to narrow that down and your class year will always be a number you can do `'([0-9]+)'` which is still a broad solution that can be narrowed down more with more information about the input.

The brackets must be escaped because they create a character class in regex and we want to match them literally.

Comment: that works great thank you, so i understand the '(.*)' and \[.*\]' with the grep command with the -only-matching argument, it saying return everything inbetween "(" character and ")" character right ? And i take it the "*" is the wildcard for everything in between them but im not sure what the "." is for? and it looks the same for bracket characters but now im not sure what the"\" are used for?

Comment: @user354662: I have added some descriptions to an edit in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the great info and followup!!! @Jesse_b

Answer (score 2):

With `bash` parameter expansion:

```
# remove matching suffix ` (*`    
ath="${TestString%% (*}"

# remove matching prefix `*) `
author="${TestString##*) }"

# remove matching prefix `*(`
classyear="${TestString##*(}"
# remove matching suffix ` [*` and add the missing `(`
classyear="(${classyear%% [*}"
```